snmpsim-command-responder failing due to No module named 'asyncore'
I am trying to setup a snmpsim from: https://github.com/inexio/snmpsim
When I try to run the following line:
snmpsim-command-responder --data-dir=./data --agent-udpv4-endpoint=127.0.0.1:1024

It returns:
line 9, in <module>
    import asyncore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asyncore'

I have tried reinstalling it using
pip install --upgrade pysnmp

I have even tried a completely fresh install with still no luck.

pip install --upgrade pysnmp worked for me.

That error is desired, as you are using the asyncore free Python 3.12.
You might switch to https://github.com/lextudio/snmpsim which is also asyncore free.

Do we not have a Python3.12 alternative to asyncore (for let's say loop method)?

@ABcDexter search engines can tell you that asyncio or anyio has been there for years.
